# SQL : matching string of one column to substring of another table column

Tags: sql, join

I have two table t1 and t3. And I need t3 which has t1 string if t1 string is present in t2 string.

```
t1-[mango, apple, Top]
t2-[{Ate mango}, {it was nice apple},{you are hero}, {apple shares top}]
```

if string of t1 matches the substring of t2 then t3 will
Output as t3

```
t3-[mango, apple, , {apple,top}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please note **Mysql** <> **Sql Server** <> **Postgresql** , so `TAG` the one you are using not all

Comment: I removed the database tags. Please only re-add the one that applies to you.

Comment: Yep, the folks here need to know if you're asking about PostgreSQL, MySQL/MariaDB, MS SQL Server, etc.  Then the specialists can tackle the problem with you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
SecondCol Result
From
(
Select
Col2 FirstCol, 
UPPER(LISTAGG(Col1, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col2)) SecondCol
From
(Select Table1.T1 Col1, Table2.T1 Col2 From Table1,Table2
Where
Length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(Table2.T1), UPPER(Table1.T1)))<>0
)
Group By Col2
);
```

[image: Screenshot after executing above Query]